# Let $f:A \to B$ be onto $B$, and let $C=\{x \in A:x \notin f(x)\}.$ Show that $C\notin B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A \to B$ be onto $B$, and let $C=\{x \in A:x \notin f(x)\}.$ Show that $C\notin B$.

I'm a bit confused as to what $C$ and $B$ are representing here.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is A ?  Whst research has been done to find the answer ?

Comment: It seems clear to me that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are *sets*, in which case you should probably write $C \not \subset C$ rather than $C \notin B$.

Comment: $A, B, C$ are all sets of sets.  $A$ is a domain of a function and $B$ is the codomain.  As $f$ is unto then $B$ is the image of $f$.  Prove that the set $C$ is not an element of the set $B$.

Comment: This is verbatim how the problem is stated.  It is quite possible for sets to be elements of sets.

Answer (score 1):

$A,B$ and $C$ are sets of sets.  $f$ is ontos so for any $D \in B$ there is an $x \in A$ so that $f(x)=D $.

In other words $B = \{f(x)|x \in A\}$.

$C = \{x\in A|x\not \in f(x)\}$.

If $C \in B$ then there is a $y \in A$ so that $f(y) = C$.

The question is, is $y \in C$?

If $y \in C$ then $y$ is one of the elements in $A$ so that $y \not \in f(y)$.  But $f(y) = C$.  So $y$ is both in $C$ and not in $C$.  That's impossible.

If $y \not \in C=f(y)$ then $y\not\in f(y)$.  So $y \in \{x\in A|x\not \in f(y)\}=C$.  So $y$ is both in $C$ and not in $C$.  That's impossible.

The only resolution is that there is no $y \in A$ so that $f(y) = C$.  But $f$ is onto so if $C\in B$ there'd be such an element in $A$.  So the only resolution is that $C \not \in B$ and there is no $y \in A$ so that $f(y) = C$.